# PHP regex periods

Tags: php, regex

How do I put a period into a PHP regular expression?

The way it is used in the code is:

```
echo(preg_match("/\$\d{1,}\./", '$645.', $matches));
```

But apparently the period in that `$645.` doesn't get recognized. Requesting tips on how to make this work.

Comment: *(sidenote)* An Ellipsis is not three dot characters `...`, but a single `…` or `&hellip;`

Comment: Regarding close/reopen: With OP's edit this is now a somewhat complete question. I would suggest, however, that OP reduces the amount of leet speak and /b/tardness in questions and comments.

Answer (score 9):

Since `.` is a special character, you need to escape it to have it literally, so `\.`.

Remember to also escape the escape character if you want to use it in a string. So if you want to write the regular expression `foo\.bar` in a string declaration, it needs to be `"foo\\.bar"`.

Comment: What I have is /\$\d{1,}\./ but when I put in $645. it doesn't recognize the regex on the period. I'm 12 and what is this?

Comment: @TOKYOTRIBE4EVAR: How do you use that regular expression?

Comment: echo(preg_match("/\$\d{1,}\./", '$645.', $matches));

Comment: @TOKYOTRIBE4EVAR: Note that `preg_match` does only return whether a match has been found or not (either `1` or `0`). You need to look at the array `$matches` to see what has been matched.

Comment: It returned a 0, which means that there was no match.  Is there something wrong with my period escape or am I just getting trolled really hard?

Comment: You need to escape the `\ ` in  `\$` too: `"/\\\$\d{1,}\./"`. With only `\$` it is replaced inside *double quotes* to `$` that means the end of the string. This would be fine in single quotes, e.g. `'\$'` → `\$`, as `\$` is not a known escape sequence. But in double quotes it is, so that `"\$"` → `$`.

Answer (score 3):

**Escape it**. The period has a special meaning within a regular expression in that it represents *any* character — it's a wildcard. To represent and match a literal `.` it needs to be escaped which is done via the backslash `\`, i.e., `\.`

```
/[0-9]\.[ab]/
```

Matches a digit, a period, and "a" or "ab", whereas

```
/[0-9].[ab]/
```

Matches a digit, any single character<sup>1</sup>, and "a" or "ab".

Be aware that PHP uses the backslash as an escape character in double-quoted string, too. In these cases you'll need to doubly escape:

```
$single = '\.';
$double = "\\.";
```

**UPDATE**
This `echo(preg_match("/\$\d{1,}./", '$645.', $matches));` could be rewritten as `echo(preg_match('/\$\d{1,}\./', '$645.', $matches));` or `echo(preg_match("/\\$\\d{1,}\\./", '$645.', $matches));`. They [both](http://www.ideone.com/O1bEF) [work](http://www.ideone.com/Sc3hN).

---

<sup>1)</sup> Not linefeeds, unless configured via the `s` modifier.

Comment: What I have is /\$[0-9]{1,}\./ but when I put in $645. it doesn't recognize the regex.  I'm 12 and what is this?

Comment: Ahh, @Gumbo elaborated on his answer too :(

Comment: So how does it not recognize the closing period on my string?

Comment: @TOKYOTRIBE4EVAR Please add examples to your question body. Also, are you serious? (*"I'm 12 and what is this?"*)

Comment: Lol no, it's just a kewl new meme that I learned about at my school's /b/ club today.

Comment: We also watched this funny video called goosh goosh and looked at all these cat pictures.  /b/ is the best site!

Comment: echo(preg_match("/\$\d{1,}\./", '$645.', $matches));

Comment: @TOKYOTRIBE4EVAR Be aware of the double-quoting (see my answer). Also, the interesting part is the `$matches`, not the return value from `preg_match()`.

Comment: @TOKYOTRIBE4EVAR Try `'/\$\d{1,}\./'`

Comment: The $matches is really kinda just there foar now but later I will have that in thar for reals.  When I did that echo, everything up to the period returns a 1 but once I add in the period there's a 0.

Comment: So I need to has single quotes around my regex?

Comment: @TOKYOTRIBE4EVAR Either that or escape properly. See my updated answer.