# Is there a way to escape the "." character in php?

Tags: php, stdclass

I have an stdClass object that I have dynamically created from a JSON using `json_decode()`. I am trying to access a field by calling `$value->V.X->processedField`
but this field has a period. This is giving me a syntax error. Is there a way to somehow escape the period in my code, or am I going to have to rename the field in my JSON?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP regex periods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4012380/php-regex-periods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
// example code

$value = json_decode('{"V.X": {"processedField":"the value"}}');
print_r($value->{"V.X"}->processedField);
// or 
$var = "V.X";
print_r($value->$var->processedField);
```

Comment: Some of these sort of questions have been asked repeatedly before, please try not to just answer without checking first.

Comment: @NigelRen - understood.. just got overzealous.

Comment: It's a common thing, the idea is to just focus the answers to limit the repetition.